# Summarize within and Calculate Geometry disagree on polygon size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

Does anyone know why the `Summarize Within` tool in ArcGIS Pro would give a larger area than the one calculated by `Calculate Geometry`?

As you can see below, the `areaKm` field (calculated by `Calculate Geometry`) does not match the summarized field given by `Summarize Within`, as denoted by the `percent cover` column.

Do these tools use different methods for calculating area? How is it possible to calculate an area *greater* than the input polygon?

[image]

Comment: A hundredth to a few thousandths of a percent seems like representation error. A more complete description of your procedure and data is needed.

Comment: You don't say if you are using [planar or geodesic area](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm#GUID-F5D7BBF8-E112-4792-9EF6-45C1979455E8) when you compute area using the Calculate Geometry tool. You are also discussing 0.01% difference, that could easily be down to rounding error caused by the different tools.

Comment: See if other polygons overlap